# How to display information from joined tables in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I would like to write a software which shows database contents in a Forms application. To make it easier to explain, I'll use a shopping list as an example.

- I have a number of lists in one table `tLists`
- I have a number of `tProductPackages` in another table
- A list can consist of many productPackages and one productPackage can be in many lists. This m:n relationship is reflected in a separate table named `tListProdPacks`.
- A productPackage contains a product. A product can have several productPackages. In every `tProductPackage` table entry, there's a foreign key FK_ProductID which references an entry in a table `tProducts`.

My forms application should navigate through all the lists using a `BindingNavigator`. In some bound controls, it should display the details of the selected list. This is working fine. (Just bound controls.)

All the list contents (entries in `tListProdPacks` for the selected `tLists` element) should be shown in a DataGridView. This is also working fine. Also the details of the productPackages (`tProductPackages` items i.e. one hop more to the next table) are displayed correctly. In this table he product value is available as ID (FK_`ProductID`) (foreign key to tProducts).

Is there a way to show the product name (contained only in `tProducts`) in the DataGridView whose DataSource is `tListProdPacks`?
(It's easy to display `tProductPackages` members, as the primary key from `tProductPackages` is referenced it `tListProdPacks` and using this ID I can show all other details from `tProductPackages` by just keep using the same valueMember but use different DisplayMember values for the single DataGridView columns [using dropdown controls in the DGV].)
But when jumping one table further (i.e. when jumping to the `tProducts` table), this does not work anymore.

I know that I could just create a custom query (join, view) to get exactly what I want, but then I cannot update the database from the dataset anymore.

Does anyone konw how to accomplish that?
(I guess that there's some easy way provided by the framework and I just don't see it, right?)

I'm not sure if I was able to describe what I would like to accomplish good enough. If not, please help me what to provide in addition.

Best regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can relate the tables using joins if they contain primary key foreign key relation . using joins u can retrieve a single result set containing all the fields which u might need.

Comment: But when using JOINs, I cannot update the database, right? What, if I want to do UPDATEs, too?

Comment: for that it is better to break all tables  and insert respective data in order but using transaction and commit properties so that if any updation failed it will roll back. u  need to do some logic there like which table to update ist and which last or do u need any id from table ist to update in second and so on